# How to install Asus N14 drivers on Ubuntu 16.04 (kernel 4.4.0-121-generic)?

Tags: drivers, wireless

The adapter sort of works out of the box without installing additional drivers, but it's very unstable - after a couple minutes speed slows down to a crawl (can't even open google), plugging it in and out helps with the issue temporarily.

Asus has a drives with `Supported Linux kernel : 2.6.x`, but nothing else. Is there any way to fix this issue?